# Generating labels for existing checkboxes for use with jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to be able to style all of the checkboxes on a page using the [jQuery UI buttons](http://jqueryui.com/button/). However, many of the buttons are unlabeled. Is there a way I could do something like this:

```
$(".unlabeled-checkbox").append("<label> </label>").button();
```

But also properly fill out the "for" attribute of the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use jQuery's "wrap" function to wrap all your checkboxes:

```
$(".unlabeled-checkbox").wrap("<label></label>");
```

That will produce HTML:

```
<label>
    <input class="unlabeled-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="a" />
</label>
<label>
    <input class="unlabeled-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="b" />
</label>
```

If you wrap `<label>` around your `<input>` you don't need the "for" attribute. Clicking on the label will trigger click on the inner checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `wrap()` method a function to execute, try this:

```
$('.unlabeled-checkbox').wrap(function() {
    return $('<label></label>').attr('for', $(this).prop('name'));
});
```

Within the function, `this` will refer to the current `.unlabeled-checkbox` element in the array.